# Does INTERSECT have a higher precedence compared to UNION?

Tags: sql, union, intersect

If we consider three single-column tables each having two rows: A = (1, 2), B = (2, 3), C = (3, 4). Then if we try `UNION` and `INTERSECT` together using parenthesis, the result is quite consistent:

- `(select * from a union select * from b) intersect select * from c` -> 3
- `select * from a union (select * from b intersect select * from c)` -> 1, 2, 3

But what about plain and simple...

- `select * from a union select * from b intersect select * from c` ?

I've tried it on several databases ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b53ec/1)) and what I empirically got is:

- In one corner we have Oracle and H2 that consider INTERSECT having the **same precedence** as UNION (hence the result is 3).
- Then, in the other corner is DB2, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MariaDB, Apache Derby, and HyperSQL that consider INTERSECT having a **higher precedence** than UNION (hence the result is 1, 2, 3).
- MySQL and Sybase ASE stay out of the ring, since they don't implement INTERSECT at all.

Do you guys know if there is any official definition on this? I skimmed the SQL-92 spec but couldn't find anything on the subject.

Comment: Interesting.  I would expect them to have the same precedence (similar to `+` and `-`).  If there is a rule in the standard, I would assume that Postgres comes closest.  That said, I would always use parentheses anyway.

Comment: On [Oracle SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) all set operations apparently have equal precedence. I don't have my ANSI SQL grammar handy (it's on another computer), so I can't speak for that right now. If you have it in front of you, you should be able to infer the precedence from it.

Comment: On what Postgres version did you try this? I get 1,2,3 in every version I tried, thus INTERSECT having higher precedence than UNION - and I think that agrees with the standard

Comment: From [Postgres documentation (SELECT page)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/sql-select.html): *"Multiple INTERSECT operators in the same SELECT statement are evaluated left to right, unless parentheses dictate otherwise. **`INTERSECT` binds more tightly than `UNION`**. That is, `A UNION B INTERSECT C` will be read as `A UNION (B INTERSECT C)`."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle has this explanatory note in its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm#SQLRF52323):

> To comply with emerging SQL standards, a future release of Oracle will give the `INTERSECT` operator greater precedence than the other set operators. Therefore, you should use parentheses to specify order of evaluation in queries that use the `INTERSECT` operator with other set operators.

So, Oracle at least thinks that equal precedence is not consistent with the standard.

As a note:  I often find the standard so inscrutable that hints like this are simpler than attempting to decipher the actual text.